# How can I use my Voxel Models into my SKScene Game?

Tags: scenekit, voxel

I have created some voxel objects in [MagicaVoxel](https://voxel.codeplex.com), a program used to create Voxel models. I finished creating one. It's export options are the following:

> obj, ply, mc, 2d, iso, slab, xraw, qb

Which one of these file formats should I choose, and how can I then IMPORT it into my SceneKit game project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

(1) Export your Voxel Object from MagicVoxel as a .OBJ file.

(2) This will create 3 files. Keep the .PNG and .OBJ files.

(3) Download a program called blender here: https://www.blender.org/

(4) Open Blender

(5) Go to [File] -> [Import] -> [Wavefront .OBJ]

(6) Navigate to your .OBJ file

(7) This will open up the .OBJ. You can rotate your object to fix any rotation problems

(8) Go to [File] -> [Export] -> [Collada .DAE]

(9) Save the new file and drag it into your XCode [SceneKit] Project!

(10) Drag in the .PNG file from Step 2 into your project too

(11) Select your .DAE file and open the right menu shown below[image: s]

(12) Open this [image: spherish thingy]

(13) Drag and drop the .PNG file from your project into the dropdown menu here. [image]

(14) Finished! Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use obj.

Read this:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3979

dae (COLLADA) is Scene Kit's favoured way of importing files.

Very few people use Scene Kit, so not anywhere near all possible file formats from all possible 3D creation tools have ever been tested, or otherwise known to work. You may come across problems with importing from obscure apps. Nobody will have the solution, you will have been (very likely) the first person to use MagicaVoxel with SceneKit.

If you have problems with obj from MagicaVoxel, find a way to get a COLLADA file from what you're making, and try to import that to SceneKit.